# Rails Rspec let with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my scenario:

I have a bounch of rspec tests

```
describe "a bunch of tests" do
   let(:my_variable) {something}
   context "10 tests" do
      ...
   end
   context "another 10 tests" do
     ...
   end
end
```

I would like to set `my_variable` to somehting else and make the same set of 20 tests I can do like this again

```
describe "a bunch of tests" do
   let(:my_variable) {something else}
   context "10 tests" do
      ...
   end
   context "another 10 tests" do
     ...
   end
end
```

I am wondering is there a better way to do the tests without so much duplicate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close them in a loop:

```
[something, something else].each do |value|
  describe "a bunch of tests" do
     let(:my_variable) { value }
     context "10 tests" do
        ...
     end
     context "another 10 tests" do
       ...
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: It works like a charm! You rock! I will accept your answer shortly